# How can fix System.InvalidOperationException = Unable to create service from type 'My type'?

Tags: c#, web-services, invalidoperationexception

I've got a web service that references a set of dlls that are currently version 6. I was given version 7 dlls to upgrade to, so I registered the new dlls in the GAC, removed the references in my project to the old dlls and added references in for the new ones. No problems so far.

I then proceeded to alter the App.config, which had references to these dlls and changed their version number to 7.0.0.0 from 6.0.0.0 and built the project. No errors or warnings.

Finally, I installed the web service and tested it out and got the following error:

> [System.InvalidOperationException] = {"Unable to create service from
>   type 'the type,
>   dll name, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=My token'."}

As I don't have access to the code in the dll's I don't know if it's something in them that's not working or whether it's perhaps a permissions / connection issue. Does anyone have some suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Press Ctrl + Q in Visual Studio in order to start texting in quick launch text box. Then type 'verbosity'. Change build output verbosity into 'Diagnostic' and analyze your build. That helps a lot in that cases.